# How to force specific version of command in /bin/sh

Tags: shell, sh, flex-lexer

When running wine-1.8.2/configure, it reports flex version is too old:

> configure: error: Your flex version is too old. Please install flex
>   version 2.5.33 or newer

wine-1.8.2/configure:

```
#! /bin/sh
# Guess values for system-dependent variables and create Makefiles.
# Generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69 for Wine 1.8.2.
...
```

I installed `flex-2.6.0` in my local area and set alias in `.cshrc`:

```
alias flex /user/user_name/TOOLS/flex-2.6.0/bin/flex
```

But configure still reports the same error message.

After I changed `FLEX=$ac_cv_prog_FLEX` to `FLEX=/user/user_name/TOOLS/flex-2.6.0/bin/flex`, it stops reporting flex old version warning.

I'm wondering how to force a specific in a script. Thanks!

Comment: You seem to have solved that issue? Why not doing it the same in a script?

Comment: I want to find a general solution, otherwise need to path every script. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should prepend the directory that you’ve installed the newer version of the `flex` command to your `PATH` environment variable. Make sure that this directory appears before the directory containing the older version so this is the first version that is found.

Setting an alias in `.cshrc` will only work for your interactive C shell. It won’t have any effect on the non-interactive Bourne-like shell (`/bin/sh`) used to interpret the `configure` script. I don’t use the C shell but you could have something like the following in your `.login` start-up file:

```
setenv PATH "/user/user_name/TOOLS/flex-2.6.0/bin/flex:$PATH"
```

If your OS uses a Bourne-style `.profile` for customising your environment, you would need to update that file using the syntax for a Bourne-like shell:

```
export PATH="/user/user_name/TOOLS/flex-2.6.0/bin/flex:$PATH"
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Not sure what's ".login start-up file". Tried adding local flex directory to PATH, but it doesn't work, it's still choosing /usr/bin/flex as default.

Comment: @Fisher `.login` contains commands that are run when you start a login C-like shell (usually to configure environment variables such as the path for finding commands). I've edited the question to include the commands that would be run for Bourne-style shell. You probably need to be more familiar with your OS start-up files to know for sure which one should be edited.